# Bilinear elements

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I am having troubles with the following exercise an I would really appreciate anyone's help.

Consider the unit square $A=[0,1]^2 \subset \mathbb R ^2.$

We call a continuous function $f:A \to \mathbb R$ affine bilinear if $f(.,y)$ is affine linear for all $y \in [0,1]$ and $f(x,.)$ is affine linear for all $x \in [0,1].$

Claim:

Let $Q(A)$be the space of affine bilinear functions on $A.$ Show that $Q(A)$ has dimension 4 and find a basis which is nodal with respect to the corners of $A.$

Comment: $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: So first:if you know the value at the four corners, then you can compute the value anywhere by the affine bilinear property. Then the second part will be to find actual affine bilinear functions with values $1,0,0,0$ at the corners, in any order.